# control.matplotlib.pzmap doesn't show zeros

Tags: python, matplotlib, controls

Make a simple transfer function with one zero and two poles and then plot its pole-zero map:

```
import control
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
tfx = control.tf([1,1],[1,1,1])
control.matlab.pzmap(tfx)
plt.show()
```

Result: Python displays a plot with two poles but no zero (python 3.6). 
Re-do the above with two small modifications as follows:

```
import control
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.style.use('classic')

tfx = control.tf([1,1],[1,1,1])
control.matlab.pzmap(tfx)
plt.show()
```

Result: Python displays a plot with two poles and one zero.
My diagnosis: matplotlib default plotting settings does not display circle marker 'o'.
My problem: I want to use matplotlib default plot settings (Because it's pretty). I DON'T want to use the 'classic' settings. How do I change the default settings to show circular markers? Here is what I've tried:

```
mpl.rcParams['patch.force_edgecolor'] = True
mpl.rcParams['patch.edgecolor'] = 'k'
mpl.rcParams['boxplot.flierprops.markeredgecolor'] = 'k'
```

But it does not change the outcome. Any ideas?

A second and slightly related issue: according to [document on control module](https://python-control.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/control.pzmap.html#control.pzmap), control.pzmap(tfx) instead of control.matlab.pzmap(tfx) should make the pole-zero plot. However that will throw a 'module is not callable' error. Odd...

Comment: What is `control`?

Answer (score 0):

In line 81 of [pzmap.py](https://github.com/python-control/python-control/blob/master/control/pzmap.py), you find

```
   if len(zeros) > 0:
        plt.scatter(real(zeros), imag(zeros), s=50, marker='o',
                    facecolors='none')
```

Here the facecolor is hardcoded to `'none'`. Hence it doesn't help to externally change the rcParams. Instead remove the `facecolors` argument from that line such that it looks like

```
plt.scatter(real(zeros), imag(zeros), s=50, marker='o')
```